# Не работает session. Потеря контекста

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, pytest, aiohttp

Приведу несколько примеров. В одних случаях, я получаю ошибку вида:

```
    def __enter__(self) -> BaseTimerContext:
        task = current_task(loop=self._loop)

        if task is None:
>           raise RuntimeError('Timeout context manager should be used '
                               'inside a task')
E           RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

В других случаях, всё работает корректно. Все примеры выполняются в связке с `pytest` (для работы требуется `pytest-asyncio==0.12.0`). Для того, чтобы было проще понять проблему, я формализую её как задачу с параметрами. В примерах есть несколько "параметров":

- `aiohttp.ClientSession()`. Создание сессии -- первый "параметр" (**A**). Будем объявлять его в различных местах: **в конструкторе**, **в теле метода**
- `client_storage = AsyncClient()`. Создание экземпляра класса -- второй "параметр" (**B**). Будем объявлять его в различных местах: **вне теста**, **в файле с тестом (ВНУТРИ функции)**, **в файле с тестом (ВНЕ функции)**.

Таким образом, у нас есть 6 различных конфигураций.

1. **A** = в конструкторе; **B** = вне теста -> Ошибка
2. **A** = в конструкторе; **B** = ВНУТРИ функции -> Корректная работа
3. **A** = в конструкторе; **B** = ВНЕ функции -> Ошибка
4. **A** = в теле метода; **B** = ВНЕ функции -> Корректная работа
5. **A** = в теле метода; **B** = ВНУТРИ функции -> Корректная работа
6. **A** = в теле метода; **B** = ВНЕ функции -> Корректная работа

REVIEW: **Таким образом, почему-то теряется сессия, если её объявлять не там, где используешь. В чём причина. Как исправить эту проблему?**

Теперь приведу рабочие примеры, чтобы стало понятнее, в чём ошибка. Буду приводить примеры также, как они расположены в списке:

## 1. **A** = в конструкторе; **B** = вне теста -> Ошибка

Импорт `client_storage` **из другого `module`**. `ClientSession` объявляется в **конструкторе**:

**tests/__init__.py**:

```
import aiohttp


class AsyncClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__session = aiohttp.ClientSession()  # Создание объекта сессии

    async def request(self):
        resp = await self.__session.request(method='get', url='https://yandex.ru')
        return resp


client_storage = AsyncClient()  # Создание экземпляра класса клиента
```

**tests/test_user.py**:

```
import pytest
import tests


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_real_request():
    await tests.client_storage.request()
    print('x')
```

## 2. **A** = в конструкторе; **B** = ВНУТРИ функции -> Корректная работа

Импорт `client_storage` **из другого `module`**. `ClientSession` объявляется в **конструкторе**:

**tests/__init__.py**:

```
import aiohttp


class AsyncClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__session = aiohttp.ClientSession()  # Создание экземпляра класса

    async def request(self):
        resp = await self.__session.request(method='get', url='https://yandex.ru')
        return resp
```

**tests/test_user.py**:

```
import pytest
import tests


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_real_request():
    client_storage = AsyncClient()  # Создание экземпляра класса клиента
    await client_storage.request()
    print('x')
```

## 3. **A** = в конструкторе; **B** = ВНЕ функции -> Ошибка

`ClientSession` объявляется в **конструкторе**. `client_storage` объявляется  **в том же `module`, в тесте**:

**tests/__init__.py**:

```
import aiohttp


class AsyncClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__session = aiohttp.ClientSession()  # Создание экземпляра класса

    async def request(self):
        resp = await self.__session.request(method='get', url='https://yandex.ru')
        return resp
```

**tests/test_user.py**:

```
import pytest
import tests

client_storage = AsyncClient()  # Создание экземпляра класса клиента

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_real_request():
    client_storage = tests.AsyncClient()
    await client_storage.request()
```

## 4. **A** = в методе; **B** = вне теста -> Корректная работа

Импорт `client_storage` **из другого `module`**. `ClientSession` объявляется в **конструкторе**:

**tests/__init__.py**:

```
import aiohttp


class AsyncClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__session = None

    async def request(self):
        self.__session = aiohttp.ClientSession()  # Создание объекта сессии
        resp = await self.__session.request(method='get', url='https://yandex.ru')
        return resp


client_storage = AsyncClient()  # Создание экземпляра класса клиента
```

**tests/test_user.py**:

```
import pytest
import tests


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_real_request():
    await tests.client_storage.request()
    print('x')
```

## 5. **A** = в методе; **B** = ВНУТРИ функции -> Корректная работа

Импорт `client_storage` **из другого `module`**. `ClientSession` объявляется в **конструкторе**:

**tests/__init__.py**:

```
import aiohttp


class AsyncClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__session = None

    async def request(self):
        self.__session = aiohttp.ClientSession()  # Создание объекта сессии
        resp = await self.__session.request(method='get', url='https://yandex.ru')
        return resp
```

**tests/test_user.py**:

```
import pytest
import tests


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_real_request():
    client_storage = AsyncClient()  # Создание экземпляра класса клиента
    await client_storage.request()
    print('x')
```

## 6. **A** = в методе; **B** = ВНЕ функции -> Корректная работа

`ClientSession` объявляется в **конструкторе**. `client_storage` объявляется  **в том же `module`, в тесте**:

**tests/__init__.py**:

```
import aiohttp


class AsyncClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__session = None

    async def request(self):
        self.__session = aiohttp.ClientSession()  # Создание объекта сессии
        resp = await self.__session.request(method='get', url='https://yandex.ru')
        return resp
```

**tests/test_user.py**:

```
import pytest
import tests

client_storage = AsyncClient()  # Создание экземпляра класса клиента

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_real_request():
    client_storage = tests.AsyncClient()
    await client_storage.request()
```

---

Таким образом, вопрос сводится к следующему: почему при определении `ClientSession` в асинхронной функции или вне её, не удаётся сделать запрос?

---

Если копнуть в глубь, оказывается, что под капотом в `aiohttp` создаётся `loop`. Если его создавать в асинхронном методе, то переменная `_thread_id is not None`. Если его создавать в других местах (там, где возникают ошибки), то она равна `None`. Проблема, видимо, кроется где-то в этом направлении.

Я попытался разобраться, в чём тут проблема: залез в `asyncio.get_event_loop()` и далее в `asyncio.get_event_loop_policy()`, которые вызывается внутри `aiohttp` и `asyncio` соответсвенно. Но здесь меня постигла неудача, поскольку `get_event_loop_policy` возвращает объект типа `_UnixDefaultEventLoopPolicy`, а снаружи оказывается уже объект другого типа с соверенно другим набором полей: `_UnixEventLoopPolicy`. Как такое происходит, я не понял.

---

Частичное решение подсказали в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1129972/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) вопросе.

```
class AsyncClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__session = None

    async def request(self):
        if self.__session is None:
            self.__session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        resp = await self.__session.request(method='get', url='https://yandex.ru')
        return resp
```

Comment: мне кажется pytest запускает новый луп

Comment: @eri скорее всего да. Добавил коммент. Пока всё выглядит очень нетривиально и магически