# Асинхронный конструктор

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, aiohttp

Мне требуется сделать асинхронный конструктор. Это требуется в случае, когда я использую `aiohttp` и создаю `ClientSession` в конструкторе.

```
class AsyncClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
```

В таком случае, так как конструктор не асинхронный, я получаю `warning`:

```
The object should be created from async function
```

Comment: А почему бы не создать ClientSession не в конструкторе, а в момент первого асинхронного использования?

Comment: @andreymal окей, да, как вариант. Спасибо. Попробую.

Comment: @andreymal полечилось. А почему асинхронный конструктор запрещено создавать? Как это объяснить?

Comment: Насчёт конструктора не знаю, а вообще в данном конкретном случае aiohttp просит использовать себя при работающем event loop, а асинхронная функция на самом деле не шибко обязательна

Comment: @andreymal если сессия инициализируется в конструктуре, то она теряется? Так?